# Example packages using expl3

Tags: programming, expl3, latex3

I'm interested in learning to program with `expl3`. While the documentation is well written - kudos to those who wrote it, must have been a major effort - it does not contain many code examples. Like probably most of us, I find that looking at examples greatly helps when getting into a new language or paradigm.

Are there some already released, useful packages out there that illustrate how to use `expl3` style key processing, flow control, data structures etc. to solve some real world document formatting tasks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are nowadays many packages on CTAN using `expl3`, although the degree to which they stick 'properly' to the approach the team is trying to encourage varies. At least in part that's because the approach itself has developed over time!

If you would like to see more-or-less 'correct' code, I'd point to my own [`notes2bib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib), which is short but is in part a testbed for me for getting things right.  On a larger scale, my [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package uses a *lot* of `expl3`: the latest release (v3 series) is intended as a 'model' package on a large scale: the development code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/main) and shows for example tests as well as the release element.

Looking beyond my own code, [Clemens Niederberger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/clemens)'s code (see https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder) is a large set of material largely using `expl3`. Or you can search your TeX installation for `ackage{expl3}` (covers both `\usepackage` and `\RequirePackage`)!

Comment: in many cases that is probably not \usepackage but \RequirePackage, so better search for "ackage{expl3}"