# List of LaTeX packages written in expl3

Tags: packages, expl3

I've seen the following question to find examples of `expl3`: [Example packages using expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341325/example-packages-using-expl3)

However, it doesn't list a lot of examples, which is a bit curious, considering the fact there are another packages already written with `expl3`, such as [`lipsum`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum?lang=en) (it has been rewritten as far as I know), [`randomwalk`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/randomwalk), or [`scontents`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scontents?lang=en). I'm asking not about packages which use a piece of it (they seem to abound) but those which make heavy use of `expl3` feature. So, I think it would be great to have a list of packages based on `expl3` as a community wiki if it makes some sense.

Comment: You can take a look at [`l3prefixes.csv`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3kernel/doc/l3prefixes.csv).  You'll find many (probably most, but not all) packages written in `expl3` there.

Comment: I didn't know about that. Thank you very much, @PhelypeOleinik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @PhelypeOleinik mentioned l3prefixes.csv is a good source as it lists all packages whose authors have registered L3 prefixes for their packages with us. Another possible (and probably fairly comprehensive) source, is to search for `\ProvidesExplPackage` across the texmf/latex tree. For me (as of today 2020-07-03) this gives 180 packages:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex @ Franks-MBP(frankmittelbach): find . -type f -exec grep -l ProvidesExplPackage {} \; 
./denisbdoc/denisbdoc.sty
./statistics/statistics.sty
./ccool/ccool.sty
./unravel/unravel.sty
./conteq/conteq.sty
./fontawesome5/fontawesome5.sty
./fontawesome5/fontawesome5-generic-helper.sty
./fontawesome5/fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty
./citeall/citeall.sty
./substances/substances.sty
./chemformula/chemformula.sty
./beuron/beuron.sty
./skrapport/skrapport-size-common.sty
./skrapport/skrapport-colortheme-skdoc.sty
./skrapport/skrapport-colortheme-violet.sty
./skrapport/skrapport-colortheme-unscathed.sty
./skrapport/skrapport-colortheme-default.sty
./skrapport/skrapport-colortheme-cruelwater.sty
./xsavebox/xsavebox.sty
./akshar/akshar.sty
./derivative/derivative.sty
./nicematrix/nicematrix.sty
./lt3graph/lt3graph.sty
./tasks/tasks.sty
./schulmathematik/schulma-physik.sty
./schulmathematik/schulma.sty
./GS1/rule-D.sty
./GS1/GS1.sty
./classics/classics.sty
./semantex/semantex.sty
./copyedit/copyedit.sty
./embrac/embrac.sty
./exsheets/exsheets.sty
./exsheets/exsheets-listings.sty
./annee-scolaire/annee-scolaire.sty
./cooking-units/cooking-units.sty
./kalendarium/kalendarium.sty
./mathcommand/mathcommand.sty
./ghsystem/ghsystem.sty
./returntogrid/returntogrid.sty
./siunitx/siunitx.sty
./chemgreek/chemgreek.sty
./aligned-overset/aligned-overset.sty
./media9/media9.sty
./media9/pdfbase.sty
./letterswitharrows/letterswitharrows.sty
./bearwear/bearwear.sty
./pmhanguljamo/pmhanguljamo.sty
./pseudo/pseudo.sty
./dashundergaps/dashundergaps.sty
./spath3/spath3.sty
./easyformat/easyformat.sty
./emoji/emoji.sty
./scontents/scontents.sty
./xpatch/xpatch.sty
./tuda-ci/tudaleaflet.cls
./tuda-ci/tudasciposter.cls
./tuda-ci/tudarules.sty
./tuda-ci/tudacolors.sty
./tuda-ci/tudaposter.cls
./endiagram/endiagram.sty
./media4svg/media4svg.sty
./pkgloader/pkgloader.sty
./lipsum/lipsum.sty
./unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty
./unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
./unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty
./kvmap/kvmap.sty
./regexpatch/regexpatch.sty
./fduthesis/fdulogo.sty
./biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext-oasymb-l3draw.sty
./xpeek/xpeek.sty
./lengthconvert/lengthconvert.sty
./langsci-avm/langsci-avm.sty
./morewrites/morewrites.sty
./morewrites/primargs.sty
./breqn/mathstyle.sty
./breqn/breqn.sty
./breqn/flexisym.sty
./algobox/algobox.sty
./chemnum/chemnum.sty
./cascade/cascade.sty
./ebproof/ebproof.sty
./xpinyin/xpinyin.sty
./duckuments/duckuments.sty
./knowledge/knowledge.sty
./download/download.sty
./hobete/hobete.sty
./mercatormap/mercatormap.sty
./tikzsymbols/tikzsymbols.sty
./chemmacros/chemmacros5.sty
./chemmacros/chemmacros.sty
./chemmacros/chemmacros4.sty
./multicolrule/multicolrule.sty
./urcls/URspecialopts.sty
./urcls/URoptions.sty
./urcls/URrules.sty
./urcls/beamerthemeUR.sty
./urcls/URpagestyles.sty
./urcls/URcolors.sty
./urcls/beamerouterthemeUR.sty
./widows-and-orphans/widows-and-orphans.sty
./bxjaholiday/bxjaholiday.sty
./cellprops/cellprops.sty
./typoaid/typoaid.sty
./secnum/secnum.sty
./l3experimental/l3benchmark/l3benchmark.sty
./l3experimental/l3color/l3color.sty
./l3experimental/l3pdf/l3pdf.sty
./l3experimental/xcoffins/xcoffins.sty
./l3experimental/xgalley/l3galley.sty
./l3experimental/xgalley/xgalley.sty
./l3experimental/l3cctab/l3cctab.sty
./l3experimental/l3draw/l3draw.sty
./l3experimental/l3str/l3str-format.sty
./l3experimental/l3graphics/l3graphics.sty
./l3experimental/l3sys-shell/l3sys-shell.sty
./notes2bib/notes2bib.sty
./l3kernel/expl3.sty
./l3kernel/expl3.ltx
./fontspec/fontspec.sty
./fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
./fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
./pdfoverlay/pdfoverlay.sty
./skmath/skmath.sty
./xcjk2uni/xCJK2uni.sty
./invoice2/invoice2.sty
./zhlipsum/zhlipsum.sty
./xsim/xsimverb.sty
./xsim/xsim.sty
./ocgx2/ocgx2.sty
./ocgx2/ocgbase.sty
./kantlipsum/kantlipsum.sty
./ducksay/ducksay.sty
./zhnumber/zhnumber.sty
./topiclongtable/topiclongtable.sty
./qrbill/qrbill.sty
./minibox/minibox.sty
./modiagram/modiagram.sty
./antanilipsum/antanilipsum.sty
./randomwalk/randomwalk.sty
./metrix/metrix.sty
./erw-l3/erw-l3.sty
./beamerappendixnote/beamerappendixnote.sty
./l3packages/xfrac/xfrac.sty
./l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.sty
./l3packages/xfp/xfp.sty
./l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
./l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
./intopdf/intopdf.sty
./phonenumbers/phonenumbers.sty
./acro/acro2.sty
./acro/acro.sty
./leadsheets/leadsheets.sty
./withargs/withargs.sty
./fnpct/fnpct.sty
./ctex/ctexcap.sty
./ctex/ctexpatch.sty
./ctex/ctexheading.sty
./ctex/ctexsize.sty
./ctex/ctexhook.sty
./ctex/ctex.sty
./xpiano/xpiano.sty
./simplebnf/simplebnf.sty
./gatherenum/gatherenum.sty
./sidenotes/sidenotes.sty
./enotez/enotez.sty
./diffcoeff/diffcoeff.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdfdocu-patches.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-space-code.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-tree-code.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-mc-code-shared.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-mc-code-generic.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-struct-code.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-mc-code-lua.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-checks-code.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-user.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-roles-code.sty
./tagpdf/tagpdf-attr-code.sty
```